# Insert div and automatically show scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm new with front-end, and I want to know how to remove the scrollbar.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sayurimizuguchi/pen/YVJKPp) example. Here doesn't show my chat. The div responsible for show is:

```
<div id="chat-column-holder" class="responsive-column content-column">
```

I insert one div blue inside my web chat, and automatically show me one scrollbar, when I have to go at the end of the page to type something.

See:
[image]

See when I go to the end of the page:

[image]

Before I insert, the scrollbar never showed.

See my atributes:

```
div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}

.topImg {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #3bb5c1;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  color: #f7f6f6;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px;

}
.topImg::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}

.topImg .topImgIcon {
 height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}


.topImg .tittle {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: px;
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: 55px;
}
```

My new div insert:

```
<div class="topImg">
  <div class="topImgIcon">
  <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" class="topImgIcon"><span class="tittle">GOOGLE</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stacking margins problem?

Comment: Man, thank u. I solved the problem with your question. I insert my div inside the scrollingchat responsible for margins. Can you please answer and I'll mark?

Comment: I just gave a suggestion, you're welcome to answer your own question and explain how you solved it - exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the problem was with `parent` and `child` (CSS), 
I just modify my `div` for my scrool `div` and works perfectly with the same size.

Answer (score 0):

can you use this code in css:

```
overflow:auto;
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.